Keyboard not working on notebook ASUS ExpertBook B1 B1502CVA-BQ0353W
i have a problem with my notebook ASUS ExpertBook B1 B1502CVA-BQ0353W.
The notebook arrived with windows installed and the keyboard was working fine.
I decided to install ubuntu 24.04.1 and then the keyboard stopped working. except for the combination fn+F4 and fn+F5 (increase/decrease luminosity) and FN+F6.
Now i'm using the laptop with an external USB keyboard to get the follow information.
$ lsb_release -a && uname -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
Release:    24.04
Codename:   noble
Linux aries 6.8.0-48-generic #48-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Sep 27 14:04:52 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

and
$ sudo dmesg | grep -i 'kbd'
[    1.123068] serio: i8042 KBD port at 0x60,0x64 irq 1
[    1.252826] i8042 kbd 00:03: hash matches
[    1.331246] atkbd serio0: Failed to deactivate keyboard on isa0060/serio0
[    1.746283] atkbd serio0: Failed to enable keyboard on isa0060/serio0
[    3.237108] systemd[1]: Starting systemd-backlight@leds:asus::kbd_backlight.service - Load/Save Screen Backlight Brightness of leds:asus::kbd_backlight...
[    3.279507] systemd[1]: systemd-backlight@leds:asus::kbd_backlight.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
[    3.279787] systemd[1]: systemd-backlight@leds:asus::kbd_backlight.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
[    3.280001] systemd[1]: Failed to start systemd-backlight@leds:asus::kbd_backlight.service - Load/Save Screen Backlight Brightness of leds:asus::kbd_backlight.

and
$ sudo dmesg | grep -i 'i8042'
[    1.119765] i8042: PNP: PS/2 Controller [PNP0303:PS2K] at 0x60,0x64 irq 1
[    1.119768] i8042: PNP: PS/2 appears to have AUX port disabled, if this is incorrect please boot with i8042.nopnp
[    1.123068] serio: i8042 KBD port at 0x60,0x64 irq 1
[    1.252826] i8042 kbd 00:03: hash matches
[    1.746345] input: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard as /devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input2

I searched online for a fix, i found and already tried to modify in /etc/default/grub
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"

with

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash i8042.probe_defer"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash i8042.reset i8042.nomux i8042.nopnp i8042.noloop"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="i8042.probe_defer mem_sleep_default=deep resume=UUID=[SWAPUUIDHERE]"

but it did not solve the problem.
Can someone help me, please?

After some research i find the solution.
If you have the same issue go to: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=218324
